# Amazon Web Services "400 Access Restricted" - Cannot log in

Tags: amazon-web-services

I signed up to AWS 1 month ago, everything it was working pretty nice, but one week ago, suddenly, I am not able to sign in. I am getting the following message:

---

400 Access Restricted.
Your access is being restricted because you appear to be located in a country or region where we do not provide services. We apologize for any inconvenience.

---

I am not able to find one place inside aws site (or google) explaining this, and I cannot get support from them because firstly I have to log in... .

I think it happened because I cleaned all cookies and history in chrome (I am not sure it is happening from that moment). But, if this would be the case, it should work from Internet Explorer, or the cookies are shared by every navigator?.

How could I get access again?

Regards

Comment: Try to use DNS proxy and log in from another country.

Comment: If you have not received an email from AWS that your account has been restricted/suspended then it might be just your browser, try a different browser or proxy.

Comment: @AlexJu what country are you trying to log in from?  Also note that AWS has multiple independent partitions... the global partition, the China partition, the GovCloud partiton, and perhaps others, each of which has its own sign-in URL.

Comment: Hi Matus, thanks for your suggestion, this is not a fix, but a way to avoid the issue. Thinking I am going to develop applications which access aws from the same country/place (for example my mobile phone, it will become a worse problem. I am trying to find the root cause and its fix. but again THANKS!

Comment: Hi Hameedullan, I have tryed IE, but I only deleted cookies in Chrome. Both of them are not working. I was not using proxy and it was working before. THe point is what did I change? or what I have to change? or who can I contact to? Thanks!

Comment: @Micheal, I am trying to access from Spain (same place, same computer as before, when it was working). I added to favorites the link working previously. Based on your comment I just have try access from https://aws.amazon.com/ and https://aws.amazon.com/es/. Both of them not working. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexJu Have you find the solution or root cause of the issue? One of my client is facing the same problem.